# Custom Search Result Box For Blog

Tags: search, blogger, box

My Blogger custom search gadget in a menu when click on this its visible but I want it to the visible always. my blog [www.bloggerspices.bid](http://www.bloggerspices.bid)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
div#searchbox {
    display: block !important;
}
```